# Can somebody tell me how can this regular expression match anything?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the javascript regular expression I'm confused about. I know that (?=) is the positive lookahead, but is there suppose to have a main expression before that?

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\w{8,}$/
```

The answer says it matches a password which is:

> at least
>   one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter and at least 8 characters that
>   are letters, numbers or the underscore

But I don't see why. Can somebody explain a little?

Comment: You need to read about regex, for now d is for digits, [a-z] is for lower case character, [A-Z] is for upper case characters, w is for word.. It will take you about an half an hour to understand atleast basics of regex if you're willing to spend your time on it.

Comment: Read [this](https://regex101.com/r/bRdYk9/1) for a comprehensive explanation of that regex ... keep that page in mind for other regex mysteries you stumble on

Comment: Why would a positive lookahead need another expression before it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it down:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\w{8,}$/
```

---

```
^                     // Match the start of the string
(?=.*\d)              // Make sure the string contains at least one digit
(?=.*[a-z])           // Make sure the string contains at least one lowercase letter
(?=.*[A-Z])           // Make sure the string contains at least one uppercase letter
\w{8,}                // Match at least eight word characters (alphanumeric or underscore)
$                     // Match the end of the string
```

---

`(?=.*PATTERN)` is a common way to ensure that a match string contains `PATTERN`.

It works because `.*` matches anything (except newline characters); the lookahead literally means "This regex should only match if you find `PATTERN` after something."

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is very clear and quite helpful.